# Fight or escape?

Tags: overwatch

There's a teamfight, my whole team gets killed and I manage to escape with low life, should I **go in and try to get a kill/annoy** or should I **back up, try to get some heals and wait for my team**?

*Let's assume that there's no overtime or any time related cases where someone would need to 100% go in and try whatever is possible.*

*Let's also assume I'm playing a hero able to deal a good amount of damage like Reaper or McGree*

*PS: If you don't want to assume and elaborate a bit more on the different posible cases, feel free to.*

Comment: Side note: If the enemy team has a Sombra, she can see where you are if your health is below 50%.  So, you may not be able to surprise them even if you think they haven't seen you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Always try to escape.**

- That one kill you might get fighting a 1v6 is not going to matter by the time the rest of your team gets back up.
- Make it as hard as possible for people to pursue you and get that last bit of ultimate charge out of your health. If you're lucky, they might overextend chasing you and run into your team.
- Give your healers a decent amount of ultimate charge from you, which otherwise they'd miss because everyone close is at full health.
- The risk of dying anyway is minimal. A just-showed-up-with-full-health team should be okay holding the line without you until you get back.

Comment: If there's a high risk of dying, should I follow this rule or is it too risky? I mean, if they then find me after, say 10 seconds, hiding would be a bit useless.

Comment: If they kill you, at least they lost 10 seconds doing it, specially if you're a good distance away from the objective. A potential problem is if your team is waiting for you to die before they move in, so in those cases it would help to let them know what your intentions are, that might probably be awkward if you don't use voice chat

Comment: Staying alive will ensure that you are there when the first players that died in your team enabling a better resistant right there instead of having to wait 10 more seconds plus the trip back to the team. This is regardless of the mode. If everyone said to himself : "everyone is dead, might as well die to get back to them" you could end up with a line of people dying one after the other as you see so often in low elo matches.

Comment: @Karlyr in low elo matches, first player respawning could also just run by you and die again for no reason :D

Comment: @Alex Good point, sad, but good point...

Comment: I'd add a caveat to this that if you think there's a good chance you will die, try to die as fast as possible. You always want to fight with all 6 members of your team, the faster you can re-group as 6, the better. Hiding for 10 seconds, then dying makes your team wait for you to re-spawn.

You'll see pro players do this a lot, jump of the map if they know they've lost the team fight.

Comment: -1 for over-generalising. If you can escape by retreating back to spawn, by all means do it. In most other situations, you will end up dying a few seconds after your team, which makes them wait the extra time for you to respawn, or makes them enter the next team fight a man down, which gives the opponents a significant advantage due to the way this game is designed around fighting as a team.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the hero that your playing, how well you know that hero, the team composition to a certain extent, the type of mode: escort, assault, control, the type of game: quick play, competitive, brawls.

If defending (escort) a payload then you need to keep the other team away from it or contest, so even if just two of them chase you then that means there are two who are further away form the payload and it might not move as quickly and if any of your team mates show up then for a few moments it's potentially two less for them to deal with.

If attacking (assault) a payload you want delay the enemy as much as possible, but depending on where the payload is, you need to decide what to do, if the payload is near a checkpoint, and your death will delay it a little then you need to decide whether it's better to delay them to give your team more time to get there or to stay alive to distract them and heal up so that you can take some of them out or weaken them.

On an control map, if it's just you and there are more enemies than you can kill with current health and dexterity, then there's little point in sacrificing your life if the other team holds the objective, but if your team holds the objective try to delay them somehow, staying alive on the objective should be your priority, rather then doing damage, so trying to move around erratically so you can last longer.

Switching roles and strategies aside, if your teams strategy is or seems to be one of those that depends on a role that only you currently fill then you might consider an early death so that you can get back with your team as soon as possible.

Most heroes have abilities that allow them to stay alive or to get away, become intimate with those abilities and use them when you can.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Иво Недев's answer has been downvoted, if you are in a bad spot, with 5 teammates dead, by attempting to stay alive and escape, you are just going to delay the respawn, meaning, delaying your next attack. Your team will have to wait for you.

In top level play, often time teams will allow the alive hero to survive for a short while, then finish them off. This runs down the clock as the attackers have to wait even longer for the next attack.

In summary, the risk of dying while escaping and delaying your respawn, is not worth the reward of being alive for the next fight instantly, as you have to wait anyway, you want to attack as a team, and die as a team.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios its always preferable to go and die as fast as possible.

True you **might** be able to escape, they **might** not chase/find you, but they should be able to figure out that only 5 people died. I'd always chase the last survivor. And when they finally catch you and kill you, your team will have started re spawning, now they have to wait 10 seconds for you to re spawn too, and that's just 10s you gave the enemy for free.

Always die if there is even the slightest chance of being caught while regrouping with your team. The possible gain is not worth the time your team waits for you to re spawn.

Previously I'd suggest that if you have an explosive ult (like death blossom) it might be worth trying to jump them and get a few kills yourself, but now with the ultimate cost going up, you best save that for the next fight.

Comment: -1 you won't see this in high level play because it's horrible advice.  By intentionally killing yourself you are making your team wait for you to respawn anyways, and also giving the enemy team extra ultimate charge.

Comment: What if I'm hiding on a quite strategic position (behind the enemies, for example), it might be worth holding it(?)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft There's more than one way to die on most of the maps ???

Comment: @Alex If you're certain you haven't been seen and they will not look for you there, you're good.

Comment: I have seen pro players throw themselves off the side of the map right after the rest of their team wipes, so that they will respawn with their team and not feed the opposing team ultimate charge.

Comment: +1 Proactively stopping the trickle in scenario is the best solution. Dying is viewed with such stigma in this game that it beggars belief.